# Changing array string inputs to integer inputs not working

Tags: python, cryptocurrency

For a project with Cryptotrading I'm trying to make my own scanner. First I collect data and append them to a list. Then I convert the list to a np.array. This array then has strings as inputs but I need to change them to Integers. When I print the np_closelist it gives all the desired values, but in an array with strings. When I try to print b (so the converted np_closelist to integers) it doesn't print anything. When I try this method in a different file with easy values it does work. Could anyone help me figure out how to fix this?
Thanks in advance!

```
import numpy as np
import talib
import websocket, json, pprint

socket = "wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/btcusdt@kline_1m"


closelist = []

def on_open(ws):
    print('open')
            
def on_close(ws):
    print('close')
    
def on_message(ws, message):
    global closelist
    json_message = json.loads(message)
 #   pprint.pprint(json_message)
    candle = json_message['k']
    is_candle_closed = candle['x']
    close = candle['c']
    high = candle['h']
    low = candle['l']
    
    if is_candle_closed:

        closelist.append(format(float(close)))
        
        closelist.append(format(float(high)))
        
        closelist.append(format(float(low)))
        np_closelist = np.array(closelist)
         
        b = np.array([int(i) for i in np_closelist])
        print(b)
        print(type(b))
        print(type(b[1]))

ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(socket, on_open=on_open, on_message=on_message, on_close=on_close)
ws.run_forever()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why did you format the floats into strings?
If you do something like:

```
    
    if is_candle_closed:

        closelist.append(float(close))
        
        closelist.append(float(high))
        
        closelist.append(float(low))
        np_closelist = np.array(closelist)
         
        b = np.array([int(i) for i in np_closelist])
        print(b)
        print(type(b))
        print(type(b[1]))
```

it should produce the desired results. It should also work if you wrap the float inside with a float cast first, like

```
b = np.array([int(float(i)) for i in np_closelist])
```

The problem comes with trying to convert a float string object directly into an int, which should normally throw an error like

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '3.0'
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer!

Uhm I'm still kinda new to programming so I dont really get what you mean with why I'm changing the floats to strings. I converted the numbers the floats and then appended them to the list (closelist). Where do I convert the floats to strings?